# cakephp2.5 2 apps one shared login

Tags: session, cakephp, shared

I have 2 databases and 2 apps

```
D:/wamp/www/main
               /app
               /child
               /cake_libraries
```

.

```
#    Database_name                      app_name    url
--------------------------------------------------------------
1    main  (have users table)            app        localhost/main
2    child (have NO users table)         child      localhost/main/child
```

core.php in app

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'my_app',
        'timeout'  => 500,  // 8 hours + 20 min, user will be logged in till 8 hours.
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '/',
            ),
        )
    );
```

core.php in child
`session.cookie_path` pointing to one step back which is `localhost/mian`

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'my_app',
        'timeout'  => 500,  // 8 hours + 20 min, user will be logged in till 8 hours.
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '../',
            ),
        )
    );
```

I checked session path in both applications pointing to same location as

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    debug(session_save_path()); //outputs 'd:/wamp/tmp'
    exit;
}
```

while I can access `$this->Session->user('id')` in main app, but in child app it gives error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SessionComponent::user() in D:\wamp\www\main\child\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 44
```

while when I try 'debug($this->Session);exit;' then

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41449884 bytes) in D:\wamp\www\main\child\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php on line 610
```

Comment: as far as i know. there is no method called user() in the Session component. that method is found only in the Auth component. and also when calling components, the Component suffix is not included e.g Session not SessionComponent

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic `SessionComponent` is the error message text, not the class name used in the code.

Comment: didnt see that, thanks for correction at @AD7six :)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know. there is no method called user() in the Session component. that method is found only in the Auth component. what's more, to achieve your goal, you could setup Auth service as REST api and then have both your apps authenticate against it